# Draw a plane in 3d with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw the plane `wx + 3y - z = 2` and show points of intersection with the parameterized line `(x,y,z) = t(1,1,5) + (0,0,-2)`. I am not sure how to get started though, the `\addplot3 coordinate` commands that I found [in the documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) seem a bit promising, but I didn't really something that I wanted to copy

Comment: In this case it is rather easy since regardless of `w` the intersection will be at `t=0`, i.e. `(x,y,z) =  (0,0,-2)`.

Comment: What If I just wanted to draw the arbitrary plane without any intersection points?

Answer (score 4):

I was too optimistic about `\closedcycle`. You can plot this setting with `\addplot3`. You need to determine the intersection point analytically (which is easy in your case, it is at `t=0`) and plot the stretches in the appropriate order. This order depends on the view angles.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={planez(\x,\y,\w)=\w*\x+3*\y-2;
linex(\t)=\t;liney(\t)=\t;linez(\t)=5*\t-2;
myw=-1;}]%<- put your favorite w here
\begin{axis}[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,zmin=-6,zmax=6,axis equal,hide axis]
 \addplot3[no marks,blue] coordinates {({linex(2)},{liney(2)},{linez(2)}) 
 ({linex(0)},{liney(0)},{linez(0)})};
 \addplot3[fill=gray,fill opacity=0.8] coordinates {(-2,-2,{planez(-2,-2,myw)})  
 (-2,2,{planez(-2,2,myw)}) 
  (2,2,{planez(2,2,myw)})  (2,-2,{planez(2,-2,myw)}) (-2,-2,{planez(-2,-2,myw)})};
 \addplot3[no marks,blue] coordinates {({linex(-2)},{liney(-2)},{linez(-2)}) 
 ({linex(0)},{liney(0)},{linez(0)})};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`pgfplots` allows you to adjust two view angles using `view={<el>}{<az>}`. For most purposes this is enough, but this does not allow you to rotate the z axis. If you need also to rotate the z axis, you may be looking for the `tikz-3dplot` package. Here you can install the "main" view with `\tdplotsetmaincoords{<theta>}{<phi>}`, and rotate also the z axis by switching to "rotated coordinates" with `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{<alpha>}{<beta>}{<gamma>}`. This is a quick example using this package.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{50}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={planez(\x,\y,\w)=\w*\x+3*\y-2;
linex(\t)=\t;liney(\t)=\t;linez(\t)=5*\t-2;
myw=-1;}]%<- put your favorite w here
 \draw plot coordinates {({linex(2)},{liney(2)},{linez(2)}) 
 ({linex(0)},{liney(0)},{linez(0)})};
 \draw[fill=gray,fill opacity=0.8] 
  (-2,-2,{planez(-2,-2,myw)}) -- (-2,2,{planez(-2,2,myw)}) --
  (2,2,{planez(2,2,myw)}) --  (2,-2,{planez(2,-2,myw)})-- cycle;
 \draw plot coordinates {({linex(-2)},{liney(-2)},{linez(-2)}) 
 ({linex(0)},{liney(0)},{linez(0)})}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: It is actually not too difficult to write a code that analytically computes the intersection point. The main hurdle IMHO is to perform vector operations. The following uses the vector parser from the [experimental library 3dtools](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex). (Copy the code in a file with the name `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` and put it somewhere where your compiler can find it, e.g. in the directory in which the example file is.) The intersection point is then obtained (and marked) with

```
 \path[intersection of line and plane={line through=LT,line  direction=LD,plane through=PT,normal=PN}] node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill]{};
```

Code with some explanations:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}
\def\ComputeIntersectionLinePlane{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myBN}{TD("(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/intersection of line and
plane/line direction})o(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/intersection of line and
plane/normal})")}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(abs(\myBN)<0.02,1,0)}% 0.02 ad hoc tolerance
\ifnum\itest=1\relax%
\message{The line and plane do not intersect in one point.^^J}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mynum}{0}%
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mynum}{ifthenelse(\itest > 0,0,TD("(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/intersection of line and
plane/plane through})-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/intersection of line and
plane/line through})o(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/intersection of line and
plane/normal})")/\myBN)}%
\fi}
\tikzset{intersection of line and plane/.style={%
/utils/exec=\tikzset{intersection of line and plane/.cd,#1}%
\ComputeIntersectionLinePlane,3d parse={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/intersection of line and
plane/line through})+\mynum*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/intersection of line and
plane/line direction})}},%
intersection of line and plane/.cd,line through/.initial=,line
direction/.initial=,plane through/.initial=,normal/.initial=}
\tikzset{projection of point on plane/.style={%
/utils/exec=\tikzset{projection of point on plane/.cd,#1},%
intersection of line and plane={%
line through=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/projection of point on plane/point},%
line direction=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/projection of point on plane/normal},%
plane through=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/projection of point on plane/plane through},%
normal=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/projection of point on plane/normal}}},%
projection of point on plane/.cd,point/.initial=,%
plane through/.initial=,normal/.initial=}

\tikzset{3d parse/.style={/utils/exec=\tdparse<#1>,%
insert path={(\pgfmathresult)}},3d coordinate/.style args={#1=#2}{%
/utils/exec=\tdparse<#2>,%
insert path={(\pgfmathresult) coordinate #1}}}
\begin{document}
Consider a line with direction $\vec B$ running through $\vec A$,
$\vec r(t)~=~\vec A+t\,\vec B$,
and a plane going through $\vec C$ and normal $\vec n$. The intersection between
the line and the plane is obtained by demanding
\[ \left(\vec r(t_0)-\vec C\right) \perp \vec n\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\left(\vec A+t_0\,\vec B-\vec C\right)\cdot\vec n~=~0\;,\]
which is the equivalent to 
\[ t_0\,\vec B\cdot \vec n~=~\left(\vec C-\vec A\right)\cdot \vec n\;.\]
Let us assume that $\vec B\cdot \vec n\ne 0$. Then 
\[t_0~=~\frac{\left(\vec C-\vec A\right)\cdot \vec n}{\vec B\cdot \vec n}
\quad\mbox{and}\quad \vec r_\mathrm{int}~=~\vec A+t_0\,\vec B\;.\] 
If $\vec B\cdot \vec n= 0$, the line is ``parallel'' to the plane, meaning
either the line is fully contained in the plane or does not intersect. In this
case, the code will spit out a message ``The line and plane do not intersect in
one point.''. Note also that this very computation also provides us with the
projection of a point on a plane. One only has to replace the line direction
$\vec B$ by the normal $\vec n$.

\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{50}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.6,line cap=round,
declare function={planez(\x,\y,\w)=\w*\x+3*\y-2;
linex(\t)=\t;liney(\t)=\t;linez(\t)=5*\t-2;
myw=-1;}]%<- put your favorite w here
 \path[overlay] (0,0,-2) coordinate (LT) % line through
  (1,1,5) coordinate (LD) % line direction
  (0,0,-2) coordinate (PT) % plane through
  (myw,3,-1) coordinate (PN) % normal
  (-1,-1,1.5) coordinate (T) % test
  ({linex(2)},{liney(2)},{linez(2)})  coordinate (L2)
  ({linex(-2)},{liney(-2)},{linez(-2)})  coordinate (L-2); 
 \path[intersection of line and plane={line through=LT,line direction=LD,
 plane through=PT,normal=PN}] coordinate(I); 
 \draw[blue,thick](L2)--(I);
 \draw[fill=gray,fill opacity=0.8] 
  (-2,-2,{planez(-2,-2,myw)}) -- (-2,2,{planez(-2,2,myw)}) --
  (2,2,{planez(2,2,myw)}) --  (2,-2,{planez(2,-2,myw)})-- cycle;
 \draw[blue,thick] (L-2) --(I) 
    node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=above:$I$]{}; 
 \path[projection of point on plane={point=T,plane through=PT,normal=PN}] coordinate(P);    
 \draw[dashed] (T) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=above:$T$]{} -- 
 (P) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=above:$P$]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a better solution with tikz-3dplot? Or is it preferred in general over pgfplots?

Comment: @EvanKim The solution with `tikz-3dplot` is not better in the sense of more automatic, it is only more minimal, and allows you to install view angles that are to the best of my knowledge not implemented in `pgfplots`.

Comment: Ahhh view angles would be nice to have. I'll take a look further into the package

Comment: @EvanKim You do have view angles in `pgfplots`, but "only" two, which can be installed with `view={<el>}{<az>}` (I always confuse `az` and `el`, it could be the other way around). These angles are in one-to-one correspondence with the arguments of `\tdplotsetmaincoords{<theta>}{<phi>}`, but in other conventions (grrrr). All these rotations leave the z axis fixed. Yet `tikz-3dplot` has `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{<alpha>}{<beta>}{<gamma>}`, which allows you to also rotate the z axis.